# What is UML class diagram connection when one class calls in one of its methods constructor of another class?

Tags: uml

Like if in the form1 form2 is created, for example, what kind of connection will it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **dependency**.

[image]

It is used for "weaker" links between two instances, for example in your case (in-method construction or invocation or even when e.g. Form2 is passed as a parameter to a method of Form1).

Related connector would be an association, used in case when e.g. Form1 would have an instance of Form2 as data member.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of instance of classifier can be described in behavioral diagrams.
You can use Activity or Sequence diagrams as depicted on pictures:

[image]   [image]